# Unable to start the existing SageMaker Notebook from AWS Glue

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have been working with AWS SageManger notebook from AWS Glue. Yesterday I stopped it.

Today I tried to start it, but the status is "Failed". I can't start it. I have some important notebooks with some code, I worry that I am going to lose that.

I tried to clone it, but that also in "Failed" status. I did "Update ETL Libraries" for the Endpoint and tried, but that also didn't help.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with the help of AWS support. 
A week back, I created a new Endpoint, switched the Notebook to use the new Endpoint and deleted the old endpoint.

Today, when I tried to stop/start the Notebook, it was looking for the deleted Endpoint. That is the issue. To fix that, I went to Sagemaker console, select and edit my Notebook, in the configuration I changed the Endpoint. After that I am able to Start the Notebook.